# Was this "roll-back edit" flag declined correctly?

Tags: discussion, moderation, flagging

My attention to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/147889/is-there-a-way-to-install-firefox-add-ons-in-chrome) was captured by the fact that answers do not match the question at all. Turned out that it was completely rewritten by the latest edit with following comment:

> Re-wrote question and title for clarity.

One of the now incorrect answers was even given by the same editor. So I've flagged the question for moderator intervention (because I don't have sufficient rep for doing roll-back) with corresponding explanation:

> rollback latest edit, it completely changes meaning of the question

Decline reason:

> sort of, but the edit makes the question in scope and allows it to
>   stay open, while still getting at the same root desire

I was kind of surprised to see such argumentation. 
Do you think flag was declined correctly?

Comment: It has been that way for years, even if it was repainting the target after shooting the arrow, I might decline just based on it being an archive at this point?  Any changes to something that old (it is that old?) should be more like updating answers, fixing links, or posting a new correct updated answer.

Comment: In this case, look at it the other way around.  The original question was off-topic and was subject to closure.  The reason given for the edit was a poor choice of words.  The edit was to turn it into an on-topic question.  It managed to preserve the essence of the question.  At the time of the original post, a lot of stuff slipped through that the site has gotten more rigorous about as time progressed.  The authors of the answers should have recognized that the question was off-topic, and answered at their own risk.  It was one of those answerers who recognized the problem and fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

I agree that the answers now seem bizarre, but I don't think we should ever make an edit that makes an on-topic question off-topic, even if that edit is a rollback. The person who asked the question could roll the edit back if he wants, but the question would probably then get closed.

If you edit the answers to fit the revised question *and preserve the meaning of the answers*, that would be good. Alternatively, you could leave a comment on the answers to tell those posters (and future readers) that the question was updated.